# How do I determine the version of the Foundation Zurb template downloaded using the CLI?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I used the foundation cli to setup the base for my website design. I want to check which version of Foundation it downloaded though because I want to know it it's the latest. Where do I go to check this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your website folder "**bower_components**", then the sub-folder "**foundation-sites**".

Now open the file named "**bower.json**"

The first few lines will say something like ...

```html
name": "foundation-sites",
"version": "6.4.1",
```

Comment: I don't have the `bower_components` folder in my website folder's root. I also checked inside `node_modules` folder and it's not there either. There is a `foundation-sites` folder inside the latter but there's now `bower.json` in it.

Comment: Actually I tried checking `package.json` and it seems to be there. Thanks for pointing me the right way!